# GKE Unable to Access webpage

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine

I have simple container created with below code

```
FROM nginx:1.22-alpine
COPY src/html /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Its working fine on the local machine but when deployed to GKE and trying to access the external ip   getting below error on the log

[image: 1]

Can you please advise

Trying to get the webpage similar to one getting on the local machine

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you share the yaml manifests used to deploy your pod to GKE ?